Kodaira-Thurston manifold
Does the Kodaira-Thurston 4-manifold admit a real spin-structure? If it is the case, could You give an explanation of it?

The explanation is easy. The only obstruction to the existence of a real spin structure is second Stifel-Whitney class (by Haefliger's theorem); KT manifold is a product of $S^1$ and 3-dimensional Heisenberg nilmanifold, which is parallelizable —  as any orientable 3-manifold — so KT itself is parallelizable.

I guess the punchline is that parallelizability kills all Stifel-Whitney classes, implying that in particular that obstruction class vanishes?

Thanks. I forgot and did not know well the parallelizability of an orientable manifold in dimension 3.
